# Access data from children and use it in parent test class.

Tags: java, constructor, dialog, boolean, joptionpane

Im trying to use the value from fiction code which is the children of Book and book also has another children Non-fiction. Below is what I've so far. I need to use something from children in the bookTest file.

```
public class Fiction extends Book  
{
private String fictionCode;
private boolean signedByAuthor;

public boolean isSignedByAuthor() 
{
    return signedByAuthor;
}

public void setSignedByAuthor(boolean signedByAuthor) 
{
     if (signedByAuthor == true) 
    {
         this.signedByAuthor = signedByAuthor;
    }
     else
     { 
         return;
         }
}

public Fiction()
{
    super(); 
    setFictionCode("");
}

 public Fiction(String title, String author, String isbn, Publisher publisher,  double price, String fictionCode,  int quantity,Date datePublished)
{
super(title, author,isbn, publisher, price, quantity,datePublished);
setFictionCode(fictionCode);
}

 public void setFictionCode(String fc)

 {
    fictionCode = fc;
 }

 public String getFictionCode()

 {
    return fictionCode;
 }


 public double calculateCharge()
 {
     double charge = this.getPrice();
     if (signedByAuthor == true) 
     {
         charge = this.getPrice()+ 20 ;
     }
     else 
     { 
         return charge; 
     }

    return charge;

 }


 public String toString()

{
return(super.toString() + " Fiction Code " + fictionCode);
}


public String printInvoice() 
{
    return null;
}

 }
```

BookTest. 
Im having a issue over here, the loop is not iterating through and i think the problem is over here but idk how to fix.

```
 Fiction f = (Fiction) book;

 if(f.isSignedByAuthor())
```

BookTest java

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.FileWriter;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Formatter;
  import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class BookTest
{

private static final Fiction Book = null;


public static void main (String[] args)
{

ArrayList <Book>list = createInstances();

writeFile(list);
}


public  static ArrayList<Book> createInstances()
{
ArrayList<Book> bookArray = new ArrayList<Book>();
String inputArray[] = new String [10];
int i = 0;
Scanner input;
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

// Read the text file and stores into inputArray where each line is stored as String.
try 
{
    input = new Scanner( new File("book.txt"));
    input.useDelimiter("\n");
    while (input.hasNext()){
        inputArray[i]=input.next();
        i++;
    }

    // dataArray defines the two dimensional array that store all the values in the line.
    String dataArray [] [] = new String [10] [11]; 

    for (int k =0; k<inputArray.length; k++)
    {
        String getLine = inputArray[k];
        String[] eachLine =getLine.split(" ");
        int length = eachLine.length;


    for ( int j=0; j<length;j++)
          {
             dataArray [k][j]= eachLine[j];
         }
    }

    for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++)

        {
            if (dataArray[l][0].equals("Fiction"))


            {
                Publisher p = new Publisher(dataArray[l][3], dataArray[l][4]);

                String[] dateSplit = (dataArray[l][10]).split("/"); // splits the date (eg. 01/1/2015 to array containg 01, 1, 2015 
                Date date = new Date(Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[0]), Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[1]),Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[2]));

                bookArray.add(new Fiction(dataArray[l][1], dataArray[l][2], dataArray[l][5],
                p, Double.parseDouble(dataArray[l][6]), dataArray[l][7], l, date));
            }

            else 
            {  NonFiction.CategoryCode categoryCode = NonFiction.CategoryCode.valueOf(dataArray[l][7]);
                Publisher p = new Publisher(dataArray[l][3], dataArray[l][4]);
                String[] dateSplit = (dataArray[l][9]).split("/");
                Date date = new Date(Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[0]), Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[1]),Integer.parseInt(dateSplit[2]));
                bookArray.add(new NonFiction(dataArray[l][1], dataArray[l][2],dataArray[l][5],
                p, Double.parseDouble(dataArray[l][6]), categoryCode, l,date));
            }
        }

} 

catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{

    e.printStackTrace();
}
return bookArray;
}


public static void writeFile(ArrayList<Book> arrayOfBook)
{
Formatter output ; 

try 
{
     output = new Formatter("updatebooks.txt");

        for ( Book t : arrayOfBook)
        {
        output.format("%s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s %s \n \n","Title:", t.getTitle(),"        Author:", t.getAuthor(),"       ISBN:", t.getIsbn(),"       Publisher:",t.getPublisher(),"      Price:",t.getPrice());
        }
        output.close();
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 



 int count = 0;           
 String message = "";
for (Book book : arrayOfBook )
{
    if( Book instanceof Fiction)
    {
    Fiction f = (Fiction) book;

    if(f.isSignedByAuthor())
     { 
         count++; 
     }
    message += String.format("%s %s \n","p ", f.isSignedByAuthor()); 
   }

 }  

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total Signed Fiction : " + count);;    
System.out.println(count);


}
}
```

Comment: I think your arrayOfBook has both Fiction and NonFiction objects. Both extends Book class. Since you are trying to cast NonFiction to Fiction class hence the error. You can not type cast until it extend that class.

Answer (score 1):

please, do likewise,

somewhere outside to for..loop,

```
       int count = 0;

     ....


    String message = "";
    for (Book book : arrayOfBook )
    {
        if( book  instanceof Fiction){
         Fiction f = (Fiction) book;
          if(f.isSignedByAuthor()){
                 count++; 
          }
         message += String.format("%s %s \n","p ", f.isSignedByAuthor()); 
        }
  } // end of for loop   
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total Signed Fiction : " + count);
```

if `book` reference-variable refers to `Fiction` object then `book instanceof Fiction` return `true`, in that case only you have to down-cast so that `ClassCastException` cover properly.

if your array contain both type of object `Non-fiction` and `Fiction` then this `instanceof` check will help better to control over `ClassCastException`.

Comment: @vishalgajeramy array contains both object of fiction and non-fiction, can you please guide me how i can use to retrieve the value just from the one from fiction which has isSignedByAuthor.

Comment: @jojo i already fix it by my answer. please follow it. just add if condition(what i mentioned into my asnwer) into your for loop.

Comment: thanks for the help it works but i got different issues, I've my constructor and data as below.private boolean signedByAuthor;
  public boolean isSignedByAuthor() 
 {
  return signedByAuthor;
 }

 public void setSignedByAuthor(boolean signedByAuthor) 
 {
   if (signedByAuthor == true) 
  {
    this.signedByAuthor = signedByAuthor;
  }
   else
   { 
    return;
   }
And I'm reading the file which is in below format.
Fiction Frankenstein Shelley Prescott GA 978-0486282114 7.99 321 true 8 5/12/2008 
Fiction Dracula Stoker Addison CA 978-0486411095 5.99 145 false 53 8/15/2005 
Thank you

Comment: @jojo i can help you more clearly, if you can post your whole code so that i can know how are you configuring Fiction objects.

Comment: @vishalgajeramy i just did let me know if you want me to post the entire bookTest file

Comment: @jojo please, post entire bookTest file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107546/discussion-between-jojo-and-vishal-gajera).

Comment: @vishalgajeramy the loop is not iterating through, it keeps on getting zero. i think the issues is over here but I'm not able to figure out how i can do it.  
          
             Fiction f = (Fiction) book;
             if(f.isSignedByAuthor()){
                 count++